# Changing default raster save settings in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4, stretch

I am clipping and saving an IMG file (created in ERDAS Imagine's MosaicPro tool) using a model in ArcCatalog 10.4.  When displayed in ArcCatalog or when opened in Arc 10.4 its symbology is set to "unique values".

How can I change the system defaults so that the model will write the file so that it is "stretched" when opened, preferably with no default stretch applied?

Comment: The default stretch of 'unique values' is because your raster is an integer, if you save as float you should get the stretched renderer by default.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I do that? The model is running from ArcCatalog, I have just set Custom Rendering Defaults but I can't find any reference to "integer" or "float".

Comment: Use the spatial analyst tool Float http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000008w000000 to write the output as floating point. Without knowing more about the model it's hard to say where to use this tool in it.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thanks very much.  Will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson it seems likely that:

> The default stretch of 'unique values' is because your raster is an
>   integer, if you save as float you should get the stretched renderer by
>   default.